# Find Control Inside ListBox?

Tags: wpf, listbox, controls, find

```
   <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem" x:Key="ListBoxItemTemplate">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <Button Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"></Button>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>     
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding S}" 
             x:Name="listBox" 
             ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListBoxItemTemplate}">
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <UniformGrid x:Name="grid" Columns="5"></UniformGrid>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    </ListBox>
```

I want to Find "grid" from  ListBox Control.Please Help Me,Thank you.

Comment: How do you want to find it? In code-behind?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get instance of Panel that holds content of ItemsControl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4744669/how-to-get-instance-of-panel-that-holds-content-of-itemscontrol)

Answer (score 11):

A couple of things to add to Meleak's answer (and this was a bit too long to put in a comment.)

Normally, the way you obtain a named element from a template in WPF is to call the template's FindName method. However, because templates are basically factories, you also needs to say which particular instance of the template you require - a single ItemsPanelTemplate may have been instantiated several times over. So you'd need something like this:

```
var grid = (UniformGrid) listBox.ItemsPanel.FindName("grid", ???);
```

But what goes in that ??? placeholder? It's not the ListBox itself - the ListBox doesn't actually use that ItemsPanel directly. Ultimately, the it's used by the ItemsPresenter in the ListBox's template. So you'd need to do this:

```
var grid = (UniformGrid) listBox.ItemsPanel.FindName("grid", myItemsPresenter);
```

...except, there's no reliable way to get hold of the ItemsPresenter either. In fact, there might not even be one - it's legal to create a template for a ListBox that just provides the hosting panel directly - there's even a special property, Panel.IsItemsHost, for this very purpose.

And that leads onto the second point I wanted to add. In scenarios where the ListBox's template doesn't use the ItemsPresenter, the ItemsPanel will go unused. So it's actually possible that the UniformGrid you're trying to get hold of doesn't even exist.

Comment: Did "Meleak's answer" refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/4104503/3195477 ?  There is no one with that username on this question anymore.

Answer (score 6):

One way to do it is to store it in code behind once it is Loaded.

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding S}"  
         x:Name="listBox"  
         ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListBoxItemTemplate}"> 
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel> 
        <ItemsPanelTemplate> 
            <UniformGrid x:Name="grid" Columns="5" Loaded="grid_Loaded"></UniformGrid> 
        </ItemsPanelTemplate> 
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel> 
</ListBox>
```

And in code behind

```
private UniformGrid m_uniformGrid = null;  
private void grid_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
{ 
    m_uniformGrid = sender as UniformGrid; 
}
```

If you want to find it from the ListBox then you can use the Visual Tree.

```
UniformGrid uniformGrid = GetVisualChild<UniformGrid>(listBox);

public static T GetVisualChild<T>(object parent) where T : Visual
{
    DependencyObject dependencyObject = parent as DependencyObject;
    return InternalGetVisualChild<T>(dependencyObject);
}
private static T InternalGetVisualChild<T>(DependencyObject parent) where T : Visual
{
    T child = default(T);

    int numVisuals = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent);
    for (int i = 0; i < numVisuals; i++)
    {
        Visual v = (Visual)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
        child = v as T;
        if (child == null)
        {
            child = GetVisualChild<T>(v);
        }
        if (child != null)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    return child;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much,i am appreciate for you.

Comment: In my case I had to use the Initialize event instead of Loaded; apparently Loaded occurs too late to use the itemsPanel object in the first Measure/Arrange pass.