# How to get instance of Panel that holds content of ItemsControl?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, controls, custom-controls

Every `ItemsControl` has its content stored in Panel right ? We can specify the panel to be used in XAML like this:

```
<ListView Name="LView">
    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate >
            <StackPanel/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
     </ListView.ItemsPanel>
</ListView>
```

My question is how to get instance of `Panel` that is used in the `ItemsPanel` property (of type `ItemsPanelTemplate`) of the particular `ItemsControl` ? For example `ListView` called `LView` from above code sample?

I cannot use `Name` property or `x:Name`, this must work for any `ItemsControl` even those using default `ItemsPanel`.

In the case its not clear please comment, I think there is very simple solution. If it seems to be complicated that's only because I cannot explain it properly.

Comment: Where are you trying to get that instance from?  Is it from the `ItemsControl` or from one of the item templates inside it?

Comment: From `ItemsPanelTemplate` exactly. I definitely don't want to get it from item templates.

Comment: Did I understand your question correctly or were you looking for something else?

Comment: @Meleak: I was able to figure out some solution after pivotnig's answer - all I needed was a fact that there is a VisualTreeHelper class. My code looks very similar to what you have provided, I'm not sure about defferences - and I'm not sure if my code always works (some leaks may be there that I'm not aware of...). I will accept one of answers after some time.

Answer (score 22):

It's a little tricky since you don't know the name of the Panel so you can't use FindName etc. This will work for most cases where an `ItemsPresenter` is present

```
private Panel GetItemsPanel(DependencyObject itemsControl)
{
    ItemsPresenter itemsPresenter = GetVisualChild<ItemsPresenter>(itemsControl);
    Panel itemsPanel = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(itemsPresenter, 0) as Panel;
    return itemsPanel;
}
```

An implementation of GetVisualChild

```
private static T GetVisualChild<T>(DependencyObject parent) where T : Visual
{
    T child = default(T);

    int numVisuals = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent);
    for (int i = 0; i < numVisuals; i++)
    {
        Visual v = (Visual)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
        child = v as T;
        if (child == null)
        {
            child = GetVisualChild<T>(v);
        }
        if (child != null)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    return child;
}
```

However, the ItemsPanel isn't always used. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4104653/84873) by Ian Griffiths for a great explanation.

Answer (score 3):

I can't provide you with working code, but have a look at
[VisualTreeHelper class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visualtreehelper.aspx).
With the [VisualTreeHelper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visualtreehelper.aspx) class you can traverse the visual tree down to your template and panel.

Answer (score 2):

```
protected Panel ItemsHost {
    get {
        return (Panel) typeof (MultiSelector).InvokeMember("ItemsHost",
            BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.GetProperty | BindingFlags.Instance,
            null, this, null);
    }
}
```

This works like a charm in my `ItemsControl`! That said, it does have `IsItemsHost="True"` on the `Panel` inside, but might even work without it.

Trick is from this thread: [Can I access ItemsHost of ItemsControl using reflection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5056728/can-i-access-itemshost-of-itemscontrol-using-reflection)

Answer (score 0):

```
   private object FindItemControl(ItemsControl itemsControl, string controlName, object item)
    {
        ContentPresenter container = itemsControl.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item) as ContentPresenter;
        container.ApplyTemplate();
        return container.ContentTemplate.FindName(controlName, container);
    }
```