# How to access Canvas instance when it is in ItemsPanel?

Tags: wpf, itemscontrol

I have changed my view from simple Canvas to ItemsControl that uses Canvas, because I want to bind Canvas children to my ViewModel.

It was like this:

```
<Canvas x:Name="worksheetCanvas">   
    <local:BlockControl DataContext="{Binding x}"/>                         
    <local:BlockControl DataContext="{Binding y}"/>                         
    <local:BlockControl DataContext="{Binding z}"/>                         
</Canvas>
```

I "moved" step forward to MVVM and now I have this:

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="itemsControl" ItemsSource="{Binding Blocks}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Canvas x:Name="worksheetCanvas">   
                <!-- Here I have some attached properties defined -->
            </Canvas>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding BlockTop}"/>
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding BlockLeft}"/>
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <local:BlockControl/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

I have to access `Canvas` from code behind (I don't want pure MVVM, there will be some code behind). I have set `x:Name` property for Canvas inside ItemsPanelTemplate, but it doesn't work:

> Error CS0103  The name 'worksheetCanvas' does not exist in the current context

I guess this is because Canvas is created after compilation and cannot be accessed like this.

What is the best (efficient) way to get my Canvas reference in this scenario?

Comment: This answer by Fredrik Hedblad should work https://stackoverflow.com/a/4744947/3137337 You need to keep in mind that your Canvas won't be captured before Window.Loaded event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a derived ItemsControl (as a WPF custom control) with a Canvas as items host and a property that makes the Canvas accessible.

```
public class CanvasItemsControl : ItemsControl
{
    static CanvasItemsControl()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(
            typeof(CanvasItemsControl),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(CanvasItemsControl)));
    }

    public Canvas Canvas { get; private set; }

    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();

        Canvas = Template.FindName("Canvas", this) as Canvas;
    }
}
```

Accessing the Canvas like this works with a default Style in `Themes/Generic.xaml` as shown below. It does not set the `ItemsPanel` property, but instead directly puts the hosting Canvas into the ControlTemplate  of the ItemsControl.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:CanvasItemsControl}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ItemsControl">
                <Canvas x:Name="Canvas" IsItemsHost="True"/>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

---

Your XAML would then look like this:

```
<local:CanvasItemsControl x:Name="itemsControl" ItemsSource="{Binding Blocks}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding BlockTop}"/>
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding BlockLeft}"/>
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <local:BlockControl/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</local:CanvasItemsControl>
```

As soon as the Template has been applied, you are able to access the `Canvas` property, e.g. in a Loaded event handler of the Window:

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    itemsControl.Canvas.Background = Brushes.AliceBlue;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for good solution with clear explanation. One more question - when exactly Template is applied? Does it happen when Window (or UserControl) is being loaded, not during Window/UserControl initialization?

Comment: Afaik, it happens before the Loaded event occurs, but after Initialized.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `VisualTreeHelper` class to find the `Canvas` in the visual tree once the `ItemsControl` has been loaded, e.g.:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Loaded += OnLoaded;
    }

    private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Canvas worksheetCanvas = FindVisualChild<Canvas>(itemsControl);
        //...
    }

    private static childItem FindVisualChild<childItem>(DependencyObject obj)
        where childItem : DependencyObject
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(obj); i++)
        {
            DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(obj, i);
            if (child != null && child is childItem)
            {
                return (childItem)child;
            }
            else
            {
                childItem childOfChild = FindVisualChild<childItem>(child);
                if (childOfChild != null)
                    return childOfChild;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: I did this for a moment, but I feel that "digging" thru VisualTree too often eats too much resources. So I stored canvas refecence in some property and when I need it very often - I just read it.

Answer (score -1):

You can create `UserControl` wrapper. And then access to canvas by `Content` property

```
<ItemsPanelTemplate>
    <local:MyCanvasWrapper>
        <Canvas x:Name="worksheetCanvas">   
            <!-- Here I have some attached properties defined -->
        </Canvas>
    </local:MyCanvasWrapper>
</ItemsPanelTemplate>
```

Code behind

```
public partial class MyCanvasWrapper : UserControl // Or ContentControl
{
    public MyCanvasWrapper()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Loaded += (s, e) => {
            var canvas = Content as Canvas;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But now how can I access local:MyCanvasWrapper instance?

Comment: @Kamil As an option you can make static List in the wrapper, and push each instance in constructor ( _instances.Add(this) ). And then find by tag, which you can set in xaml

Comment: @Kamil it depends on where u need access

Comment: @Kamil so where you need access?

Comment: In code behind, in control where ItemsPanel/Canvas is placed.